# Would or will. A question is about a certain future event

Tags: future, would

Ohad knew he had a few hours before they will open
a wormhole to Mumbo Booboo. Or Ohad knew he had a few hours before they would open a wormhole to Mumbo Booboo.

Comment: *Before* does odd things to tenses. *Would* is okay, but implies the event is susceptible to being changed. Better would be to just drop *will* from the first sentence. You can also use the past tense after *before*. "Ohad knew he had a few hours before they *opened* a wormhole to Mumbo Booboo. That is probably the most common way to phrase it.

Comment: It was your duty to post explanations of each option and another for your prospective conclusion.

How would you justify “Ohad knew he had a few hours before they will (anything)…”?
Neither "before" nor many "odd things" matter here.

Answer (score 1):

"Ohad knew he had a few hours before they would open a wormhole to Mumbo Booboo."

The sentence describes events taking place in the past. The "would" acts as the simple past of *will* here.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/would?s=t

As @Phil Sweet commented, "Ohad knew he had a few hours before they opened a wormhole to Mumbo Booboo" would be more common.

Answer (score 0):

> Ohad knew he had a few hours before they open a wormhole to Mumbo Booboo

That's English subjunctive mood as in "I ask you leave now".